# How to add CSRF verification token to my angular class

Tags: angular

This is the part of codes to understand to my question. I am using below classes and services.

```
  getAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    return new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN'))
      .set('user', localStorage.getItem('username'))
      .set('role', localStorage.getItem('role'))
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }
```

This is the sample service in my application

```
  editForm(surrenderKey: Object): Observable<any> {              
    return this.http.post(url.editSurrenderKeyReport + `${localStorage.getItem('traceId')}`, {surrRequest : surrenderKey}  ,{headers : this.apiService.getAuthorizationHeader()});
  }
```

according to requirement. I need to implement CSRF token validation. How I change my code ?

Please help me to do this. thanks

Comment: CSRF token should be generated by the server and only be active as long as the session. Verification happens on the server code. There is no standard way on how the token should be submitted to the server. Can be a header, can be a cookie.